# My custom email CSS don't work on Gmail

Tags: html, css, email, gmail

I would like to send custom emails with my CRM (Nation Builder). By "custom", I mean that I code, in HTML/CSS.

I've created an HTML file using the same structure as for a website :

```
 <html>
      <head>
        <style type="text/css">

          My CSS

        </style>
      </head>
      <body>

          My HTML body

      </body>
 </html>
```

My email appears fine on my Mail App (on my Mac), but when I open it on Gmail, the same mail seams to have no CSS.

Even weirder : I receive a newsletter from a website I like. It works perfectly on Gmail. So I've displayed it on my web browser, copied the HTML code, pasted it in Nation Builder and sent it to my Gmail. But no CSS again on Gmail (it works fine on my Apple Mail App). Even though the original mail was working fine, on the same Gmail.

Can someone explain to me why an email, that is working fine on Gmail and that I copy/paste to send it from my CRM, doesn't work ?

Thanks !

Comment: not all email clients support css. It's better to write inline styles for emails. See this link for inline html converting

Comment: But I've copied and pasted the code of an email that IS working on Gmail... That's the part I don't get

Comment: read this please: https://www.emailonacid.com/blog/article/email-development/gmail_web_app_allows_style

Comment: Check this  video - https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XnWIperMy08

Answer (score 0):

Email template using HTML and CSS is not supported by all email clients. To build your email template use HTML3 TABLE. It is supported by almost all email clients and browsers.

Also, to add design, use inline css with HTML elements. If you are using any image in template then use absolute path instead of relative path. [This link](http://webdesign.tutsplus.com/articles/build-an-html-email-template-from-scratch--webdesign-12770) might also help you to build email template.

Answer (score 0):

You want to write majority of your CSS styles inline. For example;

```
<td align="left" style="padding:40px 20px 40px 20px; font-family:sans-serif; font-size:15px; line-height:20px; color:#444444; text-align:left;">Cras mattis consectetur purus sit amet fermentum.</td>
```

or

```
<img src="path/to/img.jpg" width="600" alt="..." border="0" align="center" style="width:100%; max-width:600px;">
```

Feel free to use something like [CSS Inline](https://inliner.cm/) by Campaign Monitor the Litmus [PutsMail](https://putsmail.com/inliner). They're free and they'll do some of the heavy lifting for you.